# jQuery autocomplete plugin not working

Tags: jquery, browser, autocomplete, response

I'm using jQuery Autocomplete plugin 1.1 now, not the one included in jQuery UI.
I found that in some cases my browser will go dead. For example, when I typed in a character 'a' and there are 2 items displayed correctly. Then I type in another charactor 'z'. This time there is no matched items, but the drop-down tip does not hide, at the same time the browser lose responsing. I wonder whether my code has any problem. Following are parts of my code.

```
parse: function(data){
var rows = [];
for (var i = 0; i < max_item; i++) {
    rows[rows.length] = {
        data: items[i],
        value: items[i].fields.name,
        result: items[i].fields.name
    }
}
return rows;
},
formatItem: function(item){
    return 'balabala';
}
...
```

Comment: It would make it easier for us to help you if you provided a link to the plugin... all of the autocomplete plugins I just googled are either deprecated or very old. None of them said version 1.1. Also, the code snippet you provided is too limited, where are `max_item` and `items` defined? What calls the `parse` and `formatItem` functions? The best thing would be to provide us a "working" demo on jsFiddle.net to make it even easier to troubleshoot. If you force people that want to help to do all this work, they may just look for other questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend upgrading to the jquery ui autocomplete plugin.
http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/

I just used it on a project, and it works great.

I don't know what the rest of your code is.  but make sure you're not calling the parse function more than once...It could certainly slow down your browser

Comment: Thank you. I have found the issue, with nothing to do with the plugin.